# How can I shape the exactly?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to draw the car as my reference. But it is going very difficult. I am not getting the right idea and solution. Here is my reference car.

[image: my reference car]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\usepackage{amsthm}


\usepackage{environ}
\makeatletter
\newsavebox{\measure@tikzpicture}
\NewEnviron{scaletikzpicturetowidth}[1]{%
  \def\tikz@width{#1}%
  \def\tikzscale{1}\begin{lrbox}{\measure@tikzpicture}%
  \BODY
  \end{lrbox}%
  \pgfmathparse{#1/\wd\measure@tikzpicture}%
  \edef\tikzscale{\pgfmathresult}%
  \BODY
}
\makeatother

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\setupscalewithtikz[1][\linewidth]{%
\newsavebox{\box@tikzpicture}
\newlength{\newwidth}
\setlength{\newwidth}{#1} 
}
\NewEnviron{tikzpicture*}[1][]{%
  \begin{lrbox}{\box@tikzpicture}%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[#1]
     \BODY
  \end{tikzpicture}% 
  \end{lrbox}%
  \pgfmathsetmacro\width@scale@picture{\newwidth/\wd\box@tikzpicture}%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[#1,scale=\width@scale@picture]
    \BODY
  \end{tikzpicture}% 
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \begin{figure}
      %\centering
      \begin{center}
      \begin{scaletikzpicturetowidth}{.8\textwidth}
          \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=\tikzscale, declare function={
              excitation(\t,\w) = sin(\t*\w);
              noise = rnd - 0.5;
              source(\t) = excitation(\t,20) + noise;
              filter(\t) = 1 - abs(sin(mod(\t, 50)));
              speech(\t) = 1 + source(\t)*filter(\t);
            }]
            \draw
            [draw=black,rounded corners=6ex,very thick] (3.6,0.5) -- (1.5,.5) -- ++(0,2.5)-- ++(3,0);% --  ++(15,0) -- ++(0,-2.5)--++(-2.5,0);
            \draw[draw=black,rounded corners=5ex,very thick](14.1,3) -- (16.1,3) -- ++(0,-2.5) -- ++(-2.1,0);

            \draw[draw=black,rounded corners=1.2ex,very thick](6,0.5)--(11.6,0.5);

            \draw[very thick, rounded corners=5ex,thick]  (4.5,3) -- ++(2,2) -- ++(6.6,0) -- ++(1,-2);


            \draw [draw=black,very thick](6,.5) arc (0:180:12mm);
            \draw [draw=black,very thick](14,.5) arc (0:180:12mm);


        \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{scaletikzpicturetowidth}
      \end{center}

      \caption{Sensitivity analysis for cut Model of car}
      \label{fig:sens_1ncar}
  \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hopefully you already found a solution, but for future readers, I would recommend: a) in a raster image editor (e.g. Pinta), remove everything but the car outline; b) in a vector image editor (e.g. Inkscape), use "trace bitmap" to convert the line drawing to vector representation. Save as PDF or EPS. c) add back the other simpler elements on top in a tikzpicture, using a `\node` with `\includegraphics` to add the vector drawing.